# Return formatted value of cell and not ###### (Robust method)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a robust way to return the formatted/shown value of a cell. First a simply used the `Cell.Text` property but then I noticed a got errors when the cell was to small to fit. Then it only returns "########"

Here is a small example showing the problem. I want it to return 50.1000000 no matter how small the column is.

```
Sub Makro1()
' Desired action: Outputs text formatted value of activecell
'
    MsgBox "The value is """ & ActiveCell.Text & """"
End Sub
```

[image]

I have tried using something like this (using `Format` and the `.Value` and `.NumberFormat` properties) but I am unsure how robust it is. **Is there a better way?**

```
Sub Makro2()
' Desired action: Outputs text formatted value of activecell
'
    MsgBox "The value is """ & Format(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.NumberFormat) & """"
End Sub
```

Comment: make sure to autofit the column before trying to get the text value. `ActiveCell.Columns.AutoFit` This will make the whole visible correctly then you can use the .text.  But I prefer your second method as it does not rely on formatting the sheet properly to get the value.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes but unfortunately the second method failed if the number format was "general". However, using the `WorksheetFunction.Text` is the best option I think

Comment: Which it appears you found why, that you need to use `...Local`.  I still prefer it as it deals with the single cell and does not require the manipulation of the worksheet to get the .Text to appear correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the right answer to my own question but I still would like to leave it open for other answers. I think the most robust way is to use the worksheetfunction text `WorksheetFunction.Text` and use the `cell.NumberFormatLocal` property. It seems to handle Numberformats like "general" that the VBA `Format` function doesn't accept.

```
Sub Makro4()
' Desired action: Outputs text formatted value of activecell
'
    MsgBox "The value is """ & WorksheetFunction.Text(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.NumberFormatLocal) & """"
End Sub
```